# Hypnotoad and main namespace

Tags: perl, mojolicious, hypnotoad

How to handle the main namespace under the Hypnotoad ?

I have this small server:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Mojolicious::Lite;

use extmod;

sub hello
{
  say "hello";
}

get "/" => sub
{
  my $c = shift;
  extmod::put();
  $c->render(text=>"ok");
};

app->start;
```

...and this module:

```
use Modern::Perl;

package extmod;

sub put
{
  say ">>put:";
  ::hello();
}

1;
```

A subroutine in a module tries to call a sub in the main namespace;

This works ok under the standard mojo server. But not under the Hypnotoad:

> > put: [Tue May 30 14:20:37 2017] [error] Undefined subroutine &main::hello called at extmod.pm line 8.

Is it a feature? How to see global namespace in the module?

Comment: Did you checked [helpers](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite#Helpers)?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Put `hello` in another module used by both

Comment: @simbabque Because I have a lot of legacy functions in the main namespace

Comment: Do you know what actually is in the main namesp namespace with hypnotoad?

Comment: @simbabque No, but while looping it as a typeglob I see all my main namespace names. Are they somehow faked?